# Mypy: Generic container with some methods only valid if extra protocols apply

Tags: python, types, mypy

In mypy, how would you specify that a type `Generic` over `T` has methods that are only valid if `T` meets certain conditions?

For example, if we made a custom collection class with a `min` method, returning the smallest element in the collection:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class MyCollection(Generic[T]):
    
    def __init__(self, some_list: List[T]):
        self._storage = some_list

    def min(self) -> T: # This requires that T implements __lt__
        "Get the smallest element in the collection"
        return min(self._storage)
```

How can you tell the type system that calling `min` on `MyCollection` of `T` is only allowed if `T` implements `__lt__`?

So basically I'd like to have some methods of a generic container only be valid if extra protocols are met.

-- Useful links --

You can see from the [typehints in the standardlib for min](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/d2a7889fe0caafaa39758d332f593d537aa4dd80/stdlib/3/builtins.pyi#L1033) that they've defined a protocol for enforcing `__lt__` is implemented

```py
class SupportsLessThan(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, __other: Any) -> bool: ...

SupportsLessThanT = TypeVar("SupportsLessThanT", bound=SupportsLessThan)  # noqa: Y001
```

Comment: I don't think the python type system supports that

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you want the entire class to only accept ``T``'s that support ``<``, or do you want only the specific method to accept only such ``T``'s? In the latter case, Do you expect the method to be entirely absent or merely to not return (raise an error)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same stub file you linked, look at the type hints for `list.sort`:

```
class list(MutableSequence[_T], Generic[_T]):
    ...
    @overload
    def sort(self: List[SupportsLessThanT], *, key: None = ..., reverse: bool = ...) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def sort(self, *, key: Callable[[_T], SupportsLessThan], reverse: bool = ...) -> None: ...
```

By type hinting `self`, you can specify that a method is only applicable for certain specializations of a generic class. You can also see this [documented](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#restricted-methods-in-generic-classes) in the mypy docs.

Your `min` would thus be annotated as

```
def min(self: 'MyCollection[SupportsLessThanT]') -> SupportsLessThanT:
    ...
```

with a suitable definition of `SupportsLessThanT`.